# Issues running pip 8.0.2

Tags: python, debian, pip

I recently upgraded pip on a Debian system from version 7.1.2 to 8.0.2. When I try to run pip or pip3, I get the following error right out of the gate:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py:87: UserWarning: Support for Python 3.0-3.2 has been dropped. Future versions will fail here.
  warnings.warn(msg)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pip.utils.ui import DownloadProgressBar, DownloadProgressSpinner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.progress.bar import Bar, IncrementalBar
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/progress/bar.py", line 48
    empty_fill = u'∙'
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm having trouble making sense of this. I've tried uninstalling pip and reinstalling it with the easy-install with no luck. I have also tried downgrading back to version 7.1.2 with the command `pip install pip==7.1.2`, but this will obviously not work because pip is not working in the first place.

Can someone point me into the direction to either fix my 8.0.2 installation or revert back to 7.1.2?

I am running Python 3.4.3

Comment: Did you upgrade the System PIP withotu using proper Debian packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're still using Python 3.2:
`/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/progress/bar.py`

For Python 3.2, `foo = u'bar'` is indeed invalid syntax.

Up until release 3.3, Python 3 did not accept Python 2.x Unicode literal syntax. Python 3.3 and later [does support it](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/).

Comment: Do I need to upgrade the 3.2 package to python 3.4.3 packages to make this work? I have been using Python 3.4.3 for some time now.

Comment: I frankly have no idea what things look like in Debain 8 wrt Python 3. It [appears that 3.4 is the default](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python3); I wonder whence `/usr/local/lib/python3.2` might come at all. An approach that I'd take would be `apt-get remove python3-minimal` to have anything python3-related uninstalled, and then reinstalling python3 and friends. But I'm not an expert sysadmin by a long shot.